# Shall I keep reference to Hazelcast Map in my object?

Tags: hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast map which helps accelerating queries. My question is: shall I obtain the reference to this map each time the query method is called, or obtain the reference in my query service init method and keep it as a class member to save time when query?

Comment: What's the concern here? Are you afraid performance might be affected?

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting 5k tps on the query service in the future, which makes performance critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtaining a reference to an IMap from HazelcastInstance is a remote operation i.e. making full network roundtrip to the servers, and it adds to the overall latency of cluster operation. Hence, it is not recommended to seek reference for each caching operation; instead, maintain the reference in the app and reuse it.

Comment: What happens after changes in Hazelcast cluster? For example, when a server is down or a new server joins the cluster, shall I discard the old reference and obtain it again? Will the data be inconsistent if I keep using the old reference?

Comment: As long as your client has a live connection with the cluster, any topology changes will be adjusted on the client side on that connection. This has no impact on the state of the reference of distributed objects. So in other words, whether you loose nodes or gain a few, you can still reuse the old IMap reference. For data consistency, its not related to the state of reference. Even if your reference was lost on client and you had to acquire new from HazelcastInstance, you will find the state of the data same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant performance overhead to getting the IMap reference each time; but since it won't change it makes more sense to only get the reference once and then reuse it.

This assumes that you are already holding on to a HazelcastInstance from which you can obtain the map; getting the instance is more expensive and I wouldn't recommend recreating that each time.